# Read the given Dataset UK_Flight_2018

Tags: pandas, dataframe

1. Read the given Dataset UK_Flight_2018.

- A. Find the number of rows and columns present in it.
- B. Identify the airline names flying in the UK.
- C. Find the list of flights that origin from Vietnam.
- D. Find the number of airlines under each reporting airport.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import seaborn as sns
df1=pd.read_csv("UK_Flight_2018.csv",sep='\t')
df1
```

A. Find the number of rows and columns present in it.

```
print("Number of rows:", num_rows)
print("Number of columns:", num_columns)
```

B. Identify the airline names flying in the UK.

```
uk_airlines = df[df['origin_destination_country'] == 'UNITED KINGDOM']
uk_airline_names = uk_airlines['airline_name'].unique()
```

C. Find the list of flights that origin from Vietnam.

```
vietnam_flights = df[df['origin_destination_country'] == 'VIETNAM']
print(vietnam_flights)
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Question D: `df['reporting_airport'].value_counts()`?

Comment: Or `df.groupby('reporting_airport')['airline_name'].nunique()`